# Breakpoints are not being hit - Linux development with C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-c++, cross-platform, makefile

I am trying to make a makefile linux development project using Visual Studio and WSL.

I created a `MakeFile Project` Under the `Cross Platform` option, and connected to my WSL using ssh from the connection  manager.

When running the program (`F5`), the sources copied ,compiled and built just fine (I can see the executable via my WSL system ) . But when I place a breakpoint in any line, its not being hit. And I get this warning when placing the cursor above the breakpoint (Grayed out):

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.
```

But when debugging 'step by step' (using `F10`), I am able to debug, but not placing any breakpoints...

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Playing around with the executable paths Under `Project Properties -> Debugging ->Program/Working Directory`.
- Trying different remote build commands/ Outputs under  `Project Properties -> Remote Build->Build Command Line`. Now my Build command line is:

  ```
  cd $(RemoteRootDIr)/$(ProjectName); make
  ```
- Opening new Project / re-configure all the settings
- Make sure everything was built ok on the WSL system

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok I've figured it out! I resolved the problem just by adding -g switch to my gcc commands. gcc by default does not generate debugging symbols... see the man page for more details